# Issues with an update statement

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am having some issues with a bit of code which is meant to update an image in a database, could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The code is as follows

```
Dim SqlString1 As String = "update image set [image]=[@image],[imageno]=[@imageno],[incidentid]=[@incidentid] where [incidentid] = " & lbl_incidentid.Text & ""
     Using cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(SqlString1, conn)
        Dim image As New OleDbParameter("@image", ms1.ToArray)
        Dim imageno As New OleDbParameter("@imageno", frm_16_UploadImages.img1.Text)
        Dim incidentid As New OleDbParameter("@incidentid", Me.lbl_incidentid.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(image)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(imageno)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(incidentid)
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd1.Dispose()
        ms1.Dispose()
End Using
```

Each time this runs it returns the error message Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Now I have tested the sql string in Access, that works fine and when I use the below code to Insert instead of update it works fine.

```
Dim SqlString1 As String = "insert into [image] ([image],[imageno],[incidentid]) values ([@image],[@imageno],[@incidentid])"
      Using cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(SqlString1, conn)
         Dim image As New OleDbParameter("@image", ms1.ToArray)
         Dim imageno As New OleDbParameter("@imageno", frm_16_UploadImages.img1.Text)
         Dim incidentid As New OleDbParameter("@incidentid", Me.lbl_incidentid.Text)
         cmd1.Parameters.Add(image)
         cmd1.Parameters.Add(imageno)
         cmd1.Parameters.Add(incidentid)
         cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
         cmd1.Dispose()
         ms1.Dispose()
End Using
```

Im obviously doing something wrong with the update code, but I have no idea what it is

Comment: Your SQL in the update query doesn't have the @incidentid parameter (as it should).  `having some issues` doesn't tell us what's wrong though.  Errors?  Results?  What is wrong?

Comment: Hi @LarsTech sorry, I have updated my original post to include the actual error message. I have also amended the query to include the incidentid but I still have the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your post and shows us the code of your image and also try this one.

```
Dim SqlString1 As String = "update [image] set [image]=" & ms1.ToArray & ",[imageno]=[@imageno],[incidentid]=[@incidentid] where [incidentid] = " & lbl_incidentid.Text & ""
     Using cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(SqlString1, conn)
        Dim image As New OleDbParameter("@image", ms1.ToArray)
        Dim imageno As New OleDbParameter("@imageno", frm_16_UploadImages.img1.Text)
        Dim incidentid As New OleDbParameter("@incidentid", Me.lbl_incidentid.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(image)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(imageno)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(incidentid)
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd1.Dispose()
        ms1.Dispose()
End Using
```

Comment: I will edit my answer if its wrong and youve edit your post

Comment: by the way i noticed that because in SQL if you used a reserved word so you need to put brackets

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue the database table needed brackets in the query so it should have started

```
 Dim SqlString1 As String = "update [image] set.......
```